# How can I query an entity from a collection within an aggregate roots collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, data-modeling

Currently I am designing an API, but I am not sure whether this aggregate root is best practice in terms of useful.

**Context**

These are my classes: 
[image: Abstract visual of my entities].

**(!)** I only care about the FishHistory. I have no intention to query/request a Salmon-entity or a Carp-entity individually, nor do I need to do this on a GroupRods or Rod.

In terms of context, I am aware of the different fishes. **They differ in terms of properties (not in logic) from each other.** The reason for this interface is to enable other developers to add different logic if needed.

**Goal**

I would like to be able to add or remove controllers for different fish without touching the other controllers.

I would like to accomplish this:

```
//GET
`api/fishhistory/rods/{rodid}/salmon`
`api/fishhistory/rods/{rodid}/carp`
```

Using the repository pattern seems legit, because of a significant chance the ORM (EF6) will be changed over time.

Furthermore, I am currently working with two fish species, but this amount could grow up to let's say 10-20, maybe more over time.

**Question**

Based on the visual above and the context, I do not prefer creating repositories for each individual fish and so forth, because that would harm the maintainability - especially if the amount of different fish-entities grows up till 10-20 or ever more. I thought about creating two repositories, (1) with all the fishes and (2) with all the rods. But I am not sure if I will end up in transaction problems.

My preferable situation would be to create one repository that can be used by any fish-controller.

```
public class SalmonController : ApiController 
{
    private IFishHistoryRepository _fishHistoryRepo;

    public SalmonController(IFishHistoryRepository repo)
    {
        _fishHistoryRepo = repo;
    }

    // GET's
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/fishhistory/rods/{rodnumber}/salmons")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllSalmons(int rodnumber)
    {
         // at this point, is there a way to achieve this action without querying the carps?
    }
    // Etc here
}
```

So i.e., would this be possible somehow:

```
// Used in SalmonController
public class FishHistory
{
    GroupRods GroupRods;
    ICollection<Salmon> Fishes;
}

// Used in CarpController
public class FishHistory
{
    GroupRods GroupRods;
    ICollection<Carp> Fishes;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say: *I have no intention to query/request a Salmon-entity or a Carp-entity individually, nor do I need to do this on a GroupRods or Rod.* But then you say this `api/fishhistory/rods/{rodid}/salmon` and `api/fishhistory/rods/{rodid}/carp` and `ICollection<Salmon>` and `ICollection<Carp>`. Whether 1 or more, you will need queries for it.

Comment: Start by making one repository for one type and then try and see if you can reuse it for other types. That will guide you in the right path. If this is a read-only API, you may be able to accomplish what you want. If not read-only, even if you accomplish this, you will just end up with a huge repo that is trying to manage too many entities.

Comment: Suppose you had an excel workbook with one sheet being rods.  Do you want a separate worksheet for each type fish or do you want a separate worksheet for each fish?  If you used one worksheet for the fish what would the columns be?  How would you join the rod worksheet with the fish worksheet(s).  When designing a database (or classes) I often start with excel to come up with a design before writing any software.

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's not a readonly API, the client should be able to exchange data. Hmm, would it be better to categorize the Fish and create different repositories for each category? In that case I would put an abstract class for example on all Salmons and on each Carp. That way I could inject three repositories in each controller; namely the: GroupRodRepo, MyFishCategoryRepo and the FishHistoryRepo together with my unit of work.

Comment: You need one controller for salmon and one repo for it. Salmon controller will have a `Get()` which means get all. With EF you do not need unit of work because it already works that way. Sounds to me you need to study more to figure things out before you start implementing it.

Comment: You need one repo per domain object not per db table and for the API to be friendly, you need one controller per domain object. It will be very easy for clients to use your API if you build it that way.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say. My goal is to let the client query all salmons that belongs to a certain group of rods by calling `api/fishhistory/rods/{rodid}/salmons`. However, in this call I am trying to avoid loading my carps into memory. Especially if I would add multiple different species over time. So my `FishHistory`-entity is nothing more than a wrapper for this. `"
You need one repo per domain object"` Do you mean I have to create one repo for all salmon-species together or one repo for each individual salmon?